# Matrix Exponential equality

Tags: sequences-and-series, matrices, lie-groups, exponential-function

I was reading about the matrix exponential function and I came across this:

If $xy = yx$ then

$$ \exp(x+y) = \exp(x)\cdot\exp(y) $$

My textbook gives a proof as follows:

$$ \exp(x+y) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!}(x+y)^{k} = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum\limits_{l=0}^{k}\frac{x^{l}y^{k-l}}{l!(k-l)!}\right) = \left(\sum\limits_{p=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{p}}{p!}\right)\cdot\left(\sum\limits_{l=0}^{\infty}\frac{y^{l}}{l!}\right)$$

I have trouble understanding the last equality. I guess it has something to do with Fubini but I do not understand how an infinite and finite summation got changed into two infinite summations.

Any help will be appreciated.

**EDIT:** The sole comment was enough to get me to the answer. This is nothing but the convolution product and the result follows from [Merten's Theorem.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product)

Comment: This should help: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product

Comment: I do not know why the rendering of the Tex is so awful in this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So that this question doesn't remain in the unanswered queue:

---

We note that
$$
\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum\limits_{l=0}^{k}\frac{x^{l}y^{k-l}}{l!(k-l)!}\right) 
$$
Is simply the [Cauchy Product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product) (aka the convolution product) of the two series 
$
\sum_{p=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{p}}{p!}
$
and
$
\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}\frac{y^{l}}{l!}
$
. By [Merten's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product#Convergence_and_Mertens.27_theorem), we can deduce that
$$
\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum\limits_{l=0}^{k}\frac{x^{l}y^{k-l}}{l!(k-l)!}\right) =
\left(\sum\limits_{p=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{p}}{p!}\right)\cdot\left(\sum\limits_{l=0}^{\infty}\frac{y^{l}}{l!}\right)
$$