# Commuting matrix exponentials: necessary condition.

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-groups, lie-algebras, matrix-exponential

In related questions ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/370817/commuting-in-matrix-exponential), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/464309/matrix-exponential-equality) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/356752/show-that-eab-ea-eb)), it was shown that if $A$ and $B$ commute, then $e^A$ and $e^B$ also commute (and incidentally $e^A e^B = e^{(A+B)}$). Here, the commutative property of A and B is a sufficient condition.

Is it also a necessary condition? If no, is there another necessary condition for $e^A$ and $e^B$ to commute?

Comment: It is a necessary condition if we require that $e^{tA}$ commute with $e^{tB}$ for all $t \in \Bbb R$.  I don't know about the weaker requirement, though.

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/349180/if-ea-and-eb-commute-do-a-and-b-commute).  I'll leave it to others to decide whether this  question is a duplicate.

Comment: It appears this is a duplicate indeed. I'm really sorry, I thought I searched enough! Thanks for your answers though.

Comment: don't worry about it; duplicates like these make it easier for future potential askers to find what they need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not necessary. See [If $e^A$ and $e^B$ commute, do $A$ and $B$ commute?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/349180/if-ea-and-eb-commute-do-a-and-b-commute)

It is known, however, that if the spectra of both $A$ and $B$ are $2\pi i$-congruence-free (i.e. if the difference of every pair of eigenvalues in $A$ is not an integer multiple of $2\pi i$, and similarly for $B$), then $e^A$ and $e^B$ commute if and only if $A$ and $B$ commute. See

> Edgar M.E. Wermuth, [Two remarks on matrix exponentials](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0024379589905545), *Linear Algebra and Its Applications*, 117(1):127-132, 1989.
>
> Edgar M.E. Wermuth, [A remark on commuting operator exponentials](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1997-125-06/S0002-9939-97-03643-5/S0002-9939-97-03643-5.pdf), *Proceedings of the American Mathematical Society*, 125(6): 1685-1688, 1997.

(Remark. In the first paper above, while the author has imposed the condition that the matrices have algebraic entries, this is just a sufficient condition for the matrices to have $2\pi i$ congruence-free spectra. In the second paper, the conclusion is generalised to bounded operators with $2\pi i$-congruence-free spectra on a Banach space.)

It follows that if $e^A$ and $e^B$ commute, it's almost surely true that $A$ and $B$ commute.

See also a related discussion (and [loup blanc's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/756282) in particular) on the question [Is $\exp:\overline{\mathbb{M}}_n\to\mathbb{M}_n$ injective?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/660823/is-exp-overline-mathbbm-n-to-mathbbm-n-injective)

Comment: Thank you for the second bit (and reference) about the congruence. It was very helpful in my case.

Answer (score 2):

It is not a necessary condition.  In particular, we can take
$$
A = \pmatrix{2 \pi i & 0\\0&0}, \quad B = \pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}
$$
It's clear that $e^A = I$ commutes with $e^B$, but $A$ does not commute with $B$.